# Emacs: How to change the appearance/face of the visible-bell on a graphical frame

Tags: emacs

It seems that the visible-bell colors are the inverted default face but I cannot find where and how to control that.

I know one could set the `ring-bell-function` but that's not what I want to know here.

Comment: I imagine it's just a curses blink (though my level of understanding of curses isn't what it should be). If that is so then you cannot control its behavior mych from within Emacs.

Comment: @tripleee I thought curses is used for terminals? I'm talking about the GUI frame (on Xorg in my case).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control the appearance of the visible bell in Elisp as it is hardcoded in C (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/xterm.c). The function `XTring_bell`

```
XTring_bell (struct frame *f)
{
  if (FRAME_X_DISPLAY (f))
    {
      if (visible_bell)
    XTflash (f);
      else
```

calls `XTflash` when `visible_bell` is non-nil and uses widget functions

```
XTflash (struct frame *f)
{
  block_input ();

  {
   ...
   /* If window is tall, flash top and bottom line.  */
   ...
   /* If it is short, flash it all.  */
```

to control the bell appearance.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

```
;; quiet, please! No dinging!
(setq visible-bell nil)
(setq ring-bell-function `(lambda ()
                        (set-face-background 'default "DodgerBlue")
                        (set-face-background 'default "black")))
```

But you said you don't want to use the ring-bell-function.  Why?

Comment: because I wanted to customize the appearance of the visible bell in my Emacs theme